# Android Retrofit call at specific time daily

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-mvvm

I am creating an application (following the MVVM architecture) for which I want to send requests to the server once on a daily basis exactly at 00:05 (of user's timezone). I tried creating a service and a BroadcastReceiver but it doesn't work, the receiver never receives any signals.

The service class code is:

```
    public abstract class ReminderService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                0,
                5,
                0);
        setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void setAlarm(long timeInMillis) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReminderReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction("com.example.quotes.alarm.Broadcast");//my custom string action name
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        if (alarmManager != null) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent); //AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY //24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 (24 hours)
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("ALARMMANAGER","IS NULL");
        }
    }
}
```

And the BroadcastReceiver class is as follows:

```
public class ReminderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private QuoteRepository quoteRepository;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // fetch new quote
        Log.d("RECEIVER","RECEIVED!!!");
        quoteRepository = new QuoteRepository((Application) context.getApplicationContext());
        quoteRepository.getRandomQuote();
        Quote quote = quoteRepository.getSingleQuoteLiveData().getValue();
        quoteRepository.insertQuote(new QuoteEntity(quote.getId(), quote.getQuoteText(), quote.getAuthor()));

    }
}
```

In my Main Activity:

```
 //checking if alarm is working with pendingIntent
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReminderReceiver.class);//the same as up
 intent.setAction("com.example.quotes.alarm.Broadcast");//my custom string action name
 boolean isWorking = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) != null);//just changed the flag
 Log.d(TAG, "alarm is " + (isWorking ? "" : "not ") + "working...");
```

The following code is in the Manifest:

```
 <service
            android:name=".alarm.ReminderService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>

        <receiver android:name=".alarm.ReminderReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.quotes.alarms.Broadcast">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Have you considered [Work Manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)?

Comment: @rdias002 I have, but I have no idea how it works (I would love a tutorial on Retrofit and Work Manager), and I would like to find out why BroadcastReceiver is not working.